# Unable to add Entity Framework to Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, nuget-package

I keep getting a "Failed to add reference to 'EntityFramework'" error when I attempt to add the Entity Framework to my project using the Nuget Package Manager. Screenshots of the steps leading up to the error are listed below:
[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]

[image]
[image]
I tried repairing my VS installation, but that didn't work. In my VM environment, I'm running Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, and I don't have any problems adding EF to a solution/project. Any ideas on what's causing the error in VS Enterprise 2015?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: did  you update your `nuget package manager`?

Comment: @esiprogrammer I attempted to update the npm from the package manager console with the command "PM> Get-Package -Updates
No package updates are available from the current package source for project 'DatabaseFirstDemo'." Is this method correct?

Comment: @esiprogrammerI'm still having the same problem.

Comment: run vs as administrator and go to Tools->Extension Manager menu

Comment: @esiprogrammer I updated to v3.3.0.167 of NPM, but I continue to get the same error.

Comment: @esiprogrammer I was able to install v6.1.2 of EF, but v6.1.3 keeps failing.